# 'Spring' is not exported from 'react-spring'

Tags: reactjs

I installed 'npm i react-spring' and imported it

```
import { Spring } from 'react-spring';


ReactDOM.render(

  <Provider store={store}>
              <FistBump />  
          <MonkeyPic />
    <Stylesheet primary={true} />
      <App />
  
  
    <Spring
       from={{ marginLeft: 0 }}
       to={{marginRight: 5}}>
      <Gorilla />
    </Spring>

  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

After saving it tells me:

./src/index.js
Attempted import error: 'Spring' is not exported from 'react-spring'.

Comment: https://github.com/FilipZafran/redux-todo-step_by_step

Comment: source:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8yn3-WpVV8&ab_channel=TraversyMedia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to import as below

```
import {Spring} from 'react-spring/renderprops'
```

as per: https://www.react-spring.io/docs/props/spring

Comment: seems like this got me somewhere, but now I have the following error...

Comment: TypeError: children is not a function Spring.render node_modules/react-spring/renderprops.js:1554